# how to estimate overlap coefficient in SAS using the percentage of overlapping area between the two density functions

Tags: sas

I have created two graphs using density functions but don't know how to  calculate the overlap coefficient in SAS using the following codes:

```
proc sgplot data=combined_cohort;
 density S_exposed / legendlabel='exposed' lineattrs=(pattern=solid);
 density S_unexposed  / legendlabel='unexposed' lineattrs=(pattern=solid);
   keylegend / location=inside position=topright across=1;
 xaxis display=(nolabel);
```

Comment: How do you define the overlap coefficient?

Comment: the overlapping coefficient should be an estimate of the percentage of overlapping area under the two density function